# how to store hbase tables permanently on VM

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I am doing some simple stuff in HBASE on VM by using bulk load . Would like to how how to persist the tables permanently in HBASE. If i restart the VM tables are gone so, do we have any command to store it permanently .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start HBase in local mode (i.e., using the file system and not HDFS), then all of the data is by default saved in /tmp.  Some linux systems will wipe /tmp on reboot (i.e. turning the VM on and off).

There are three ways of dealing with this

1. use HDFS to store your data
2. change your hbase-site.xml file to point to a location other than /tmp for your data
3. never, ever, shutdown your VM (seriously, don't do this)

The correct property to set, quoting from the [HBase book](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html):

```
<property>
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>file:///DIRECTORY/hbase</value>
 </property>
```

where DIRECTORY is replaced with whereever you want to store data